# Filtering JSON based on sub array in a Power Automate Flow

Tags: power-automate

I have some json data that I would like to filter in a Power Automate Flow.

A simplified version of the json is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "ItemId": "1",
    "Blah": "test1",
    "CustomFieldArray": [
      {
        "Name": "Code",
        "Value": "A"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Category",
        "Value": "Test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ItemId": "2",
    "Blah": "test2",
    "CustomFieldArray": [
      {
        "Name": "Code",
        "Value": "B"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Category",
        "Value": "Test"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For example, I wish to filter items based on Name = "Code" and Value = "A". I should be left with the item with ItemId 1 in that case.

I can't figure out how to do this in Power Automate. It would be nice to change the data structure, but this is the way the data is, and I'm trying to work out if this is possible in Power Automate without changing the data itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I had to fix your JSON, it wasn't complete.

Secondly, filtering on sub array information isn't what I'd call easy.  However, to get around the limitations, you can perform a bit of trickery.

[image: Filter Array]

Prior to the step above, I create a variable of type `Array` and called it **Array**.

In the step above, the left hand side expression is ...

```
string(item()?['CustomFieldArray'])
```

... and the **contains** comparison on the right hand side is simply as you can see, a string with the appropriate filter value ...

```
{"Name":"Code","Value":"A"}
```

... it's not an expression or a proper object, just a string.

If you need to enhance it to cater for case sensitive values, just set everything to lower case using the `toLower` expression on the left.

Although it's hard to see, that will produce your desired result ...

[image: Result]

... you can see by the vertical scrollbars that it's reduced the size of the array.